# FullCalendar - Add unavailable when no event is set and set background color

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using jquery fullcalendar for one of my project to set appointments for doctors.

here doctor should be able to specify the available timings between 9-5 in weekdays and if this is not set the **background color of The spans of time not occupied by an event should be grey** or some color and text should b **displayed as "unavailable" in those span.**

I tried rendering: 'inverse-background' which is not working atm. could anyone did this or have any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and revise your question with the relevant information

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and solved it by flipping the concept - rather than leaving it as a coloured background as a "non-event"- which was still clickable , I created events based off the not-available times and added those as events called unavailable. This means that for example, 00:00 to 8:59 an event occurred and was rendered but was the unavailable timeslot and therefore I could control the click eventsand CSS styling etc. Same for the end of the day 18:00 - 23:59 was another event that was "unavailable". Works a treat!

It also allowed me to set different start times and end times for different practitioners and display each practitioners schedule with the "on" times displayed and functional.

Comment: Thanks mate for reply...**do I have to do it for all users???**...rather I am looking for something where non event slots should be colored as grey to make them look different and I see the content div **fc-widget-content**  when no event is set that should contain text as "unavailable" so that if user want they can set it to available which will b an event...Thanks

Comment: yes I understood the problem and had spent time a while ago trying to come up with an elegant solution but couldn't. My solution was to set the times of all practioners in the database - then pull each out into an array of availabilty and create the events dynamically so that each practitioners day would be built  on the fly. No worries - what works for one doesn't work for all,Good luck with your quest.